# Exchange 2016 configuration

Tags: exchange-2016

After I installed Exchange 2016, all https access to the default website (https://mydomin.com)  goes to OWA.  When I use just http, our normal business website is shown.

Is it possible to have https access go to our normal business website and if so, how?

Thanks in advance

Gary